# few questions about twillio service

Tags: helper

first i'm sorry for my weak English, i hope you can understand me.
I want to start using twillio and i have few questions that I hope you can help me with.

1. If i have a existing Europe number (for example, Belgium number), can i use that number with twilio?
2. If i configured a forward calling to another number and the phone is off, the call still will be forwarded (for example, i configured with twilio that all calls are coming to my Belgium number, will be forwarded to my Greece number and the Belgium phone is off, will the call still be forwarded?)
3. Can I forward messages?
4. Are twilio offering internet roaming service?

Thats it for now,
thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a specific service and should go to their support

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

1. Today we [do not support porting phone numbers from international carriers to Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/porting/can-i-port-an-international-number-to-twilio)
2. I think there is some misunderstanding of how Twilio works for this scenario.  Twilio does not provide direct cellular service.  We don't provide SIM's so there is no way to assign a mobile device  a phone number hosted by Twilio.

   In your scenario you could purchase a Belgian phone number from Twilio and then configure that number to forward inbound calls to that number to the cell number assigned to your actual cell phone.  Twilio can also detect if the call was not answered and in that case you can direct Twilio to try dialing another number.  Keep in mind however that even if your phone is off, its likely that your cell carrier would direct the call to voicemail, which would likely cause Twilio to consider the call answered.  There are ways around that which I can explain if your interested.
3. Are you asking about forwarding SMS messages?  If the answer is yes, unfortunately we do not yet offer SMS-enabled Belgian phone numbers.
4. Again, we are not an an [MVNO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_virtual_network_operator), so we don't provide direct service for mobile phones.

Hope that helps.